# При использовании SQLALCHEMY ошибка Access denied

Tags: python, веб-программирование, flask, sqlalchemy

при использовании sqlalchemy иногда ловлю такую ошибку при коннекте с базе, при этом исправляется она повторной попыткой запроса, с чем это может быть связано? не было бы доступа оно бы вообще не работало, а  так иногда проскакивает...может изза плохого коннекшина ?

> sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError
>   ProgrammingError: (mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError) 1045 (28000): Access denied for user ''@' (using password: YES)
>   (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)

кто сталкивался с таким?
PS: коннекчусь к базе так:

> app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']        = 'mysql+mysqlconnector://{}:{}@{}:{}/{}'.format(mysql_db_user,
>                                                                                   mysql_db_pass,
>                                                                                   mysql_db_host,
>                                                                                   mysql_db_port,
>                                                                                   mysql_db_name)

И эта строка коннекта тоже меня бесит, есть ли какой-то более адекватный способ задавать параметры подключения? Зарание спасибо.

Comment: Что значит "иногда" и "повторной"? Иногда падает конкретная строка и перезапуск всего когда или в каких-то местах подключение работает, а в других нет? И сомневаюсь, что ошибка в библиотеке, поэтому предполагаю, что в вашем коде подключение как-то криво организовано, и для дальнейших мыслей нужно увидеть больше кода.

Comment: Приложение перезапускать не нужно, при загрузке страницы приложение получает данные из базы и загружает их на страницу, и иногда случается то что описано выше, решается нажатием F5, в коде сделано все как в офф мануале, почти копипаст